# How to assert that a specific request header is sent in a outgoing request C#

Tags: c#, mstest

I want to test a scenario

As part of the API logic a header will be sent as part of an outgoing http call.
like

```
    public class MyClass{
            public NewResponse MySepcificHeaderApi(HttpRequestMessage request) {
               if( OnSomeCondition()){
                   // i want to test whether this header added or not
                   request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-Specific-Header", "some values");
               }    
               var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateHttpClient("Some name");
               var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
               
               // here we lost X-Specific-Header, as we taken only status code 
               // from the original response.
               return NewResponse(response.StatusCode); 
            }
        }
```

So now if I want to test the API `MySepcificHeaderApi` .

```
// arrange
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(Get, "some uri");

// act
var response = new MyClass().MySepcificHeaderApi(request);

//assert
response.Headers.should().Contain("X-Spcific-Header"); // will fail, because the actual requet details are missed out from original response in MyClass.MySepcificHeaderApi()
```

Comment: Use middleware and intercept the http traffic.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this we can use `HttpRequestInterceptionBuilder` and `WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint>` to solve the issue.

```
// arrange
CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>? webApplicationFactory = new CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>();
HttpClientInterceptorOptions? interceptorOptions = webApplicationFactory.InterceptorOptions;
interceptorOptions.BeginScope();
var httpClient = webApplicationFactory.CreateClient();
var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
new HttpRequestInterceptionBuilder()
    .Requests()
    .WithInterceptionCallback(i =>
    {
        foreach (var httpRequestHeader in i.Headers)
        {
            headers.Add(httpRequestHeader.Key,
                httpRequestHeader.Value.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    })
    .ForPost()
    .ForHttp()
    .ForHost("localhost")
    .ForPath($"some uri")
    .ForRequestHeader("X-Specific-Header", "some values")
    .Responds()
    .WithStatus(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    .RegisterWith(interceptorOptions);
// the above HttpRequestInterceptionBuilder will return OK status, only is the request contains the "X-Specific-Header, that way we are asserting the header is added.

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(Get, "http://localhost/some uri");

// act
var response = new MyClass().MySepcificHeaderApi(request);

//assert
reponse.StatusCode.Should().Be(Ok);
headers.Should().ContainKey("X-Specific-Header");
headers["X-Specific-Header"].Should().Be("some values");
```